# Error: use of deleted function in inheritance

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to learn the inheritance. I wrote the code and I got the following error that I have never seen before when compiling with gcc6.3.0

```
class Book{
public:
    string title;
    string author;
    int page;

    Book(string Title, string Author, int Page){  
        title = Title;
        author = Author;
        page= Page;
    }

void setAuthor(string Author){
    author = Author;
}

string getAuthor(){
    return author;
}

string toString(){
    cout << "Title: " << title << "\nAuthor: " << author << "\nPage: " << page << endl;
}        

};

class SpecialEdtionBook : public Book{

public:
    void Special(){
        cout << "Special editions is out"<< endl;
    }

};
```

> error: test1.cpp: In function 'int main()': test1.cpp:47:23: error:
> use of deleted function 'SpecialEdtionBook::SpecialEdtionBook()'
> SpecialEdtionBook book2;

What does this error mean? What should I be looking for when this type of error occurs?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+error+use+of+deleted+function please! Also, check the formatting of the code in your question and also make sure it contains a [mcve].

Comment: `Book` doesn't have a default constructor, and neither does `SpecialEdtionBook`. The declaration `SpecialEdtionBook book2;` tries to initialize the instance with the default constructor, but one doesn't exist.